# How to deal with texture distortion caused by "squaring" textures, and the interactions with mipmapping?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, mipmaps, pvrtc

Suppose I have a texture which is naturally not square (for example, a photographic texture of something with a 4:1 aspect ratio). And suppose that I want to use PVRTC compression to display this texture on an iOS device, which requires that the texture be square. If I scale up the texture so that it is square during compression, the result is a very blurry image when the texture is viewed from a distance.

I believe that this caused by mipmapping. Since the mipmap filter sees the new larger stretched dimension, it uses that to choose a low mip level, which is actually not correct, since those pixels were just stretched to that size. If it looked at the other dimension, it would choose a higher resolution mip level.

This theory is confirmed (somewhat) by the observation that if I leave the texture in a format that doesn't have to be square, the mipmap versions look just dandy.

There is a LOD Bias parameter, but the docs say that is applied to both dimensions. It seems like what is called for is a way to bias the LOD but only in one dimension (that is, to bias it toward more resolution in the dimension of the texture which was scaled up).

Other than chopping up the geometry to allow the use of square subsets of the original texture (which is infeasible, give our production pipeline), does anyone have any clever hacks they've used to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you have a few options, depending on what you can do with, say, the vertex UVs.

[Hmm Just realised that in the following I'm assuming that the V coordinates run from the top to the bottom... you'll need to allow for me being old school :-) ]

The first thing that comes to mind is to take your 4N*N (X*Y) source texture and repeat it 4x vertically to give a 4N*4N texture, and then adjust the V coordinates on the model to be 1/4 of their current values. This won't save you much in terms of **memory** (since it effectively means a 4bpp PVRTC becomes 4x larger) but it will *still* save bandwidth and cache space, since the other parts of the texture won't be accessed. MIP mapping will also work all the way down to 1x1 textures.

Alternatively, if you want to save a bit of space and you have a pair of 4N*N textures, you could try packing them together into a "sort of" 4N*4N atlas. Put the first texture in the top N rows, then follow it by the N/2 of the top rows. The pack the bottom N/2 rows of the 2nd texture, followed by the second texture, and then the top N/2 rows. Finally, do the bottom N/2 rows of the first texture.  For the UVs that access the first texture, do the same divide by 4 for the V parameter. For the second texture, you'll need to divide by 4 and add 0.5
This should work fine until the MIP map level is so small that the two textures are being blended together... but I doubt that will really be an issue.

Comment: We composite textures together wherever we can, so this only comes up when we have a repeating texture. The first trick you mention would actually work for that case, but the second trick is out of the question here. Going in and changing the geometry is not something I'd love to do (what if there is UV animation, for example).But I concur that this would fix the blurring. Any other clever ideas?

Comment: None at the moment. It's all a bit of a shame that the interface only exposes square textures when the hardware happily supports rectangular, power of two PVRTC textures.

Comment: Do you have a reference on that? I assumed that the square requirement was coming from the hardware. I'd like to file a bug report with Apple if this isn't needed!

Comment: Actual references? No. But FWIW, the PVRtextool compressor from Imagination (i.e. PowerVR) does rectangular POT textures and the extension spec (http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/IMG/IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc.txt) doesn't specifically limit it. It may be a backwards compatibility limitation for the earliest iPhones <shrug>

Comment: This is getting interesting! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerVR says that Apple uses SGX (not MBX) PowerVR. This page says that the SGX hardware supports non-square, but the drivers do not necessarily: http://www.imgtec.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=627 . So it appears you may be right that this is a driver issue, not a hardware issue. In our case, we're requiring iOS 5, so the earliest hardware is already excluded. Time to file the bug report!

Comment: I have reported this to Apple: Bug ID# 11140779